# How do I force Bootstrap 3 to use the desktop menu?

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wondering how I can 'force' a page created with Bootstrap 3 to scale down a menu without using the hamburger layout. I'm designing a web app where having a full menu (it's only seven one-word items) is important.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">Toggle navigation </button>
      <span class="navbar-brand">The Burkean <br> Pentad</span></div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Intro <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Act</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Scene</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Agent</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Agency</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Purpose</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated my answer, working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zu12pxzq/1/**

just add following css styles -

```
.collapse {
    display: block !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
  float:left !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    display:none !important;
}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Looks like I'm halfway there: the menu items have disappeared in the mobile layout.

Comment: Added to the original question and made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/phobrla/zu12pxzq/

Comment: just remove the #navbar from '#navbar.collapse' , i will update my answer